# Unable to open and close browsers

Tags: tosca

[image: Scenario from My Tosca Application]

I have this scenario of 4 redundant test cases as marked below and the basic idea is running the 4 test cases from the folder highlighted in green.

The last step for each test case is closing the browser and
the first test case step is open a new browser window, open URL, validate a field and then last step, close the browser.

The issue I am facing is the first test case runs fine, but after the execution of the first test case, Tosca is not able to reopen another browser window to execute the second test case. Please help with a solution why Tosca is not able to open a second browser window. The executor simply waits for a certain amount of time before showing a timeout error message in Scrapbook o/p.

Comment: Are you trying to run all of the test cases in 1 go? If you run just the second test case on it's own does it run successfully? Maybe try adding all the test cases to an execution list and run.

Answer (score 0):

After closing the browser in the first test case give 2 sec wait. What's happening here is that when Tosca tries to close the browser, it executes a command which will take some time to execute, but Tosca will go to the next test case and  tries to open the browser in the  the second test case.

By the time Tosca opens the browser in the second test case, it will be closed by the first test case close browser command.

A simple wait after closing the browser should fix this issue. I have come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, a "wait" helps, but with "TBox Window Operation" you can use a "Wait On Close".

- **OpenUrl**

  - **Url:**  http://www.deepl.com
- **TBox Window Operation**

  - **Caption:**  DeepL *
  - **Operation:**    Wait On Close

[image: Wait On Close in Window Operation]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of standard modules open URL and then enter the value of the browser you need to open. Using the wait standard module to verify if the URL is opened. Now, use tbox window operation to close the browser where caption will be the name of the browser page and operation will be closed.